# Convergence problem $\sum \left(1-n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have to check convergence of: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right).$$ I have no idea but I only check that $\lim \ n\left(1-n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=0$.

Comment: Does the summation start from $n=1$?

Comment: Yes, from 1 to infinity

Comment: Note that, for large $n$, by Taylor expansion $\sin(\frac{1}{n})=\frac1n+\frac{1}{3!n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})$, hence the series goes $\sim \frac{1}{n^2}$, hence converges.

Comment: @KennyLau Both are correct

Answer (score 3):

Note that, for large $n$, by Taylor expansion $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac1n+\frac{1}{3!n^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right),$$ hence the summands are of the form
$$1-n\cdot\left(\frac1n+\frac{1}{3!n^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{3!n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$
Thus the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

As can be shown using $x>\sin(x)$, the function

$$\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}$$ has a negative derivative for $x\ge0$. By L'Hospital, the limit at $0$ is $\dfrac16$ so that

$$0\le\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}\le\frac16$$ and

$$0\le1-\frac{\sin(x)}x\le\frac{x^2}6.$$

Summing for all $\dfrac1n$, by the Basel problem the series converges and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\le\frac{\pi^2}{36}.$$

---

By numerical evaluation, the gap is just $3.3\%$.